# openssl SSL_Connect with err 2

Tags: openssl

Iam a new member into this forum.

Issue:

I have to integrate openssl in my project.project is implemented with gsoap.

in "r = SSL_connect(soap->ssl)) <= 0)" 
SSL_connect call is unable to make a connection to the server.Both server and client are in local host

I see server is ready to accept the connections, as I see below connection established with netstat command:

TCP    cspxppgudepu:15000     cspxppgudepu.com:0  LISTENING 
TCP    cspxppgudepu:15000     localhost:2864         ESTABLISHED

Above 15000 port is for server.

Below is client connection: 
 TCP    cspxppgudepu:16000     cspxppgudepu.com:0  LISTENING

But SSL_connect is unable to connect.It is always failing with return code -1 & err 2.

With out SSL connection,simple TCP conection, both ends are able to connect and communicate. Below network configuration  settings for without SSL

My network configuration settings for with openssl:

```
    <NetworkConfig> 
            <Server Location="https://127.0.0.1:15000" /> 
            <Client Location="https://127.0.0.1:16000" />
```

I have taken both client & server authentication to false.

Thanks in advance. 
Pradeep Reddy.

---

An update,

SSL_connect is failing with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ.I understand that client is waiting on server to write some data.But I dont understand what to change code in server side.

please let me know, how to go from this.

---

SSL communcation is working fine now if I give root certificate cacert.pem on both server and client and authentication is set to true.Instead of giving the same root certificate cacert.pem I have given clientcert.pem and servercert.pem in soap_ssl_client_context() and soap_ssl_server_context() calls respectively. 
This time Handshake is failed with below error at client side:"error:14090086:lib(20):func(144):reason(134)" 
and server side "error:14094418:lib(20):func(148):reason(1048)"

But both client certificate and server certificate are generated from root certificate "cacert.pem" below comands.

Command:openssl x509 -req -in clientreq.pem -sha1 -extensions usr_cert -CA root.pem -CAkey root.pem -CAcreateserial -out clientcert.pem -days 1095 
and 
Command:openssl x509 -req -in serverreq.pem -sha1 -extensions usr_cert -CA root.pem -CAkey root.pem -CAcreateserial -out servercert.pem -days 1095 
error I understood as "error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca".
But both certificates are from same root CA cacertpem. Please provide if you have any fix.
I could not edit the post, so posting the answer.
Thanks,
Pradeep.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must establish the TCP connection before you call `SSL_connect()`.  `SSL_connect()` just sets up the SSL session, and it expects that the file descriptor you set with `SSL_set_fd()` is already connected to the other side.

Secondly, you must call `SSL_accept()` on the server side (again, after the underlying TCP connection has already been set up).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set that the CA is trusted on your client code with:

```
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *CAfile, const char *CApath)
```

You can find at OpenSSL documentation about how to use that method - it's pretty straightforward:

http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html